# Unable to display width of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, width

I can't seem to display the width of the text using jquery as the user fills in the input box. I followed [Jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/). Maybe I missed something I just can't seem to see it :(

As soon as the text is displayed by keyup event, the width should be displayed as the text changes, right? For further info, I have been trying to rebuild an app like this: [Text changing application](http://www.woodlandmanufacturing.com/aluminum-letters.html#wmiBox)

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CodePitbull/yan5L66L/)

```
<!--form begin-->
<form id="textchanger" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
    <p>Preview:</p>
    <!--display user input--> <span id="text-preview"><p id="prev" class="form_result"></p></span>

    <p id="textCount"></p>
    <!--display width-->
    <p id="textWidth"></p>
    <label class="sign-text">Enter your text
        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" class="form-control enter-text-field validation-passed" value="Enter Your Text">
    </label>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#text').keyup(function (e, w) {
        $("#prev").html($(this).val());

        var txtwidth = $("#text-preview").width();
        $("#textWidth").text("Approx. Width: " + txtwidth + " px.");
    }).keypress(function (e) {
        return /[a-z0-9.-\s]/i.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    });
});
```

Comment: Not working in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a css `display: inline-block;` on your `$("#text-preview")`.

The span is filling the entire width so it will never report the right size. Use browser developer tools to inspect the width.

http://jsfiddle.net/xxL0Lpb1/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just add `inline-block` for text preview
http://jsfiddle.net/yan5L66L/2/

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/yan5L66L/1/)**

Some changes are in order. `<p>` is a block element. It has width of the container, not the text inside.
so

```
    $('#text').keyup(function (e, w) {
        $("#text-preview").html($(this).val());

        var txtwidth = $("#text-preview").width();
        $("#textWidth").text("Approx. Width: " + txtwidth + " px.");
    }).keypress(function (e) {
        return /[a-z0-9.-\s]/i.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    });

<p>Preview:</p>
<!--display user input--> 
<span id="text-preview"></span>
```